# Any implications of using explicit Hash Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

By using hash joins I have been able to bring my execution time from `800 ms` to `467ms`. This my query:

```
exec sp_executesql N';With cte as (Select peta_rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  d.LastStatusChangedDateTime  desc )  
                                                , d.DocumentID
                                                , u.Username
                                                , it.Abbreviation AS ITypeAbbreviation
                                                , ig.Abbreviation AS IGroupAbbreviation

                                From Documents d
                                Inner Hash Join Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID Inner Join IGroupes ig on ig.IGroupID = d.IGroupID
                                Inner Hash Join ITypes it on it.ITypeID = d.ITypeID Where 1=1  ) Select cte.DocumentID, d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime, d.CreatedByAccountID, d.JurisdictionID, 
                        d.LastStatusChangedDateTime as LastStatusChangedDateTime
                        ,  d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID,cte.IGroupAbbreviation, cte.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,
                       cte.ITypeAbbreviation, d.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation,  ds.Name as DocumentStatusName,
                        ( SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN cte.DocumentID = (
                                SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID
                                FROM  Documents doc
                                WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID
                                        AND doc.DocumentStatusID = d.DocumentStatusID
                                ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime) 
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS BIT)
                        ) AS CanChangeStatus ,

                        Upper((Select Top 1 Stuff( (Select ''='' + dbo.GetDocumentNameFromParamsWithPartyType(Business, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, t.Abbreviation, NameTypeID, pt.Abbreviation, IsGrantor, IsGrantee)  From DocumentNames dn
                                Left Hash Join Titles t
                                    on dn.TitleID = t.TitleID               
                                Left Hash Join PartyTypes pt
                                    On pt.PartyTypeID = dn.PartyTypeID
                                        Where DocumentID = cte.DocumentID
                                            For XML PATH('''')),1,1,''''))) as FlatDocumentName, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE) AS TotalRecords

                        FROM cte Inner JOin Documents d ON d.DocumentID = cte.DocumentID Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On
                        d.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On cte.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                    Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = d.JurisdictionID Where 1=1 And peta_rn>@7 AND peta_rn<=@8 Order by peta_rn',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 int,@8 int',@0=1,@1=5,@2=9,@3=1,@4=5,@5=9,@6=1,@7=97450,@8=97500
```

I want to know if there are any implications of using Hash Joins in the result set? It looks OK to me but I am not sure if it would break my existing app or not.

Comment: A cte is just syntax and is evaluated on those joins.  I would materialize the cte to a #temp with a PK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this "break your app"? Almost certainly not, unless forcing a `HASH JOIN` hits a particular bug in the database engine that your other execution plan does not hit, but realistically the chances of this happening are practically zero. The main question is whether the data will be the same with or without the hint, and the answer is almost certainly "yes".

Joins like `MERGE`, `HASH`, etc are physical operations, so what you are specifically doing is forcing a particular physicaly operation when the query is run. In isolation this is making the above query run faster in this one instance, but there are larger consequences as well that need to be considered. For example, a `HASH JOIN` will build interim hash tables, which may have to be stored in tempdb, so will increase the resource usage in that area. Will this create a new bottleneck for other operations? Impossible to say until you perform a larger set of tests.

Finally, apply a hint like this locks you into that particular join type. Can you honestly say you have done absolutely everything to help SQL Server make the right choice without a hint? Right now SQL Server is building a plan based on the current table statistics and the input parameters you're passing in. If you rebuild statistics or pass different parameters and force a new plan, you might get different results, but with a hint you're taking the risk that what seems to work in one instance will apply to all instances in the future.

Does this mean you shouldn't use the hint? No, if you genuinely think this will improve your system then go for it! Just consider the bigger picture - there are definitely implications of using a hint like this, but if the reward (a faster query) is worth it then it might be a good option.